# Org-mode : estimating deadlines for parent headlines

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've never been fond of scheduling dates.

I cannot find a way to make org-mode to, given a bunch of tasks, subtasks and estimates, compute the deadline of each task and the parent tasks for me.

In my dream, I would say that I work 8 hours a day, and my week-days are Mo-Fr, and estimate tasks in hours, days and weeks.
Emacs would compute the dates for me, starting... now. Or starting at a schedule date.

Here is a question that could be on the path to my dream: [org-mode: creation time range from effort estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044588/org-mode-creation-time-range-from-effort-estimate/23067020#23067020)

**Before**

```
* Bunch of tasks
  SCHEDULED: <2015-12-15 mar.>
** Substasks1
*** TODO task1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   7:30
    :END:
*** TODO task2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   7:30
    :END:
*** TODO task3
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   3:15
    :END:
** Subtask2
*** TODO task4
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   0:30
    :END:
*** TODO task5
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   3:15
    :END:
*** TODO task6
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   7:30
    :END:
*** TODO task7
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   15:00
    :END:
```

**After**

```
* Bunch of tasks
  DEADLINE: <2015-12-22 mar.> SCHEDULED: <2015-12-15 mar.>
** Substasks1
   DEADLINE: <2015-12-17 jeu.>
*** TODO task1
    DEADLINE: <2015-12-15 mar.>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   7:30
    :END:
*** TODO task2
    DEADLINE: <2015-12-16 mer.>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   7:30
    :END:
*** TODO task3
    DEADLINE: <2015-12-16 mer.>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :Effort:   3:15
    :END:
** Subtask2
...
```

Comment: I am voting to close because the original poster does not really know what he/she wants, and has apparently not invested any significant time to find a solution before asking this question.  Please read the org-mode tutorials -- Google a bit for . . .

Comment: @lawlist As to the precision of what I want, this seems pretty clear in my mind. Please help me edit the question if it is not understandable on the first read. Concerning the time invested, I spent 6-8 hours focused on org-mode before writing this question. In the docs/tutorials, I found many ways to manually put a timestamp, schedule date or deadline, but now way to have them computed from the :EFFORT: property.

Comment: In the example that you linked, the original poster placed a before and after specific example -- the question had a specific answer.  Your question does not seek a specific answer, and leaves it open for interpretation.  Your question also makes it sound like you want a tutorial of built-in features, versus coding something specific.  This is not the proper forum for a tutorial, and there are many good org-mode tutorials that are already available on the internet.  Your question gives the impression that you have not spent the time to read any org-mode tutorials regarding scheduling.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for your comments. I edited the question. Doest it make more sense?